# datetime error while inserting into database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

I have field with datetime datatype in my database.

I am parsing date as follows:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fileDate, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

While inserting it into database I am doing it as follows:

```
cmd= new SqlCommand("insert into closingStock values('" + subLine[1].ToString() +
     "','" + subLine[2].ToString() + "','" + DateTime.Parse(subLine[3]) + "','" +
     subLine[10].ToString() + "','" + dt + "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It is giving me following error:

```
String was not recognized as valid datetime.
```

What mistake am I making?

Comment: Mistake : You are not using parameterized queries, Please do read http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml

Comment: I thought its parsing related error

Comment: 1) try printing that sql command, to see what you really send to the database; 2) read up on sql parameters, they will save you a whole lot of trouble (including this date format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try with [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
string strDate = "25/03/2013";           
DateTime datDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate , new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" },
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate);
Console.WriteLine(datDate);
```

**Edit 1**
I think the exception you are getting beacause of `DateTime.Parse(subLine[3])`, check the `DateTime` format for this .

Comment: can you share table stucture

Comment: can you tell me what is the datetime format for `DateTime.Parse(subLine[3])`

Comment: datetime datatype is there for it

Comment: khub khub bhalo aachhe. *1000*

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this error several times, I use an string as my datetime field:

```
string myDate= DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()
   + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() 
   + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() 
   + "." + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
```

then I insert this string in my table, it works fine!

Comment: i datetime field in my db for date storage not nvarchar

Comment: I know what you are doing, I always use datetime and this technique works fine for me (SQL Server 2008)

Comment: You should really try a simpler approach. There's no guarantee that calling `DateTime.Now` 6 times will return 6 times the exact same date and time. Prefer a single (and lighter) command like `DateTime.Now.ToString("s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` or `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss")`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parametrized queries. That way you don't have to worry about formatting correctly for your query, only make it a correct DateTime.

Given your correctly parsed DateTime (as per Arshad's answer):

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime subline3Date;
//...
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into closingStock values(?,?,?,?,?)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(subLine[1]);
cmd.Parameters.Add(subLine[2]);
cmd.Parameters.Add(subline3Date);
cmd.Parameters.Add(subLine[10]);
cmd.Parameters.Add(dt);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: every one suggest me this. what difference does it makes? i want to know it.

Comment: First of all, you don't have to bother with how dates should be presented, say `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, `'yyyy.MM.dd'` or `#MM/dd/yy#`. The SqlCommand deals with that formatting, adds the quotes it needs. Same for strings and numbers, it formats how it needs.
Also, if a string has quotes, that too will be handled.
The worst cast scenario is if you try to enter other SQL code as a value, say `");Drop All Tables;`. With your approach, that would delete your database. With paramaters, you will record it and keep your database.